NetSuite: How to enter landed cost into itemReceipt via API
NetSuite 2024.1
I've manually created itemReceipt (IR39) by receiving purchase order.
On itemReceipt under Items & Expenses there is Landed Cost column with an icon. Once clicked, it brings a small form like this:

When I call GET /itemReceipt/{id} I am getting this:

Documentation for itemReceipt shows this:

Questions:

why don't I see form values in resulting JSON of POST /itemReceipt/{id}?
How do I add landed cost values via API call?

